# Angular - Change button after Audio ends

Tags: angular

I want to click the button to play audio. If the audio ends, I can change the button from the play button to the replay button.

This is my code.

```
audioObj = new Audio();
playAudio() {
    if (!this.isPlaying) {
      this.isPlaying = true;
      this.audioObj.play();
    
    // I'm already tried using this.audioObj.play().then(()=>{...}) but it's not working. 
       It doesn't wait for the end of audio but executes it immediately after the play button is clicked.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener and then perform the action in a callback, like this:

```js
audioObj = new Audio();
playAudio() {
    this.audioObj.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      // action here
    })

    if (!this.isPlaying) {
      this.isPlaying = true;
      this.audioObj.play();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: asking because i'm curious, does this not run the risk of adding a listener every time the audio is played ?

Comment: @Dince12 every audioObj is a completely new object, so doesn't seem risky. But indeed one needs to be careful when adding event listeners